# How to fix "int" is not subscriptable error?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, python-3.x

I keep getting the error 'int' object is not substitutable.  I know my problem is within "def filaray()"  I also know making "num" a list would be more efficient.  However this is an assignment and I'm pretty sure we can only use array's.  Is there a way I can fix my error while not making "num" a list?

Comment: Uh, lists are the normal "array" type in python. There is an `array` type, but it's not frequently used.   You're doing num = a random int so many times, then returning the last int. You're not constructing a list or an array at all.

Comment: I suggest copying & pasting the exact error that you're getting so we know exactly what's going wrong.

Comment: 'lists are the normal "array" type'
...and `[0]` is indeed a list. Can you give a precise error message? Where is the line/column of the error?

Comment: `num` is initialized as a list (`[0]`) but then overwritten by `random.randint`. Try `num.append(random.randint(0, 9))` instead.

Comment: You should read [the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) to familiarize yourself with the basics of lists and indexing in Python.

Comment: http://screencap.net/f/1661b2d8.png here's a look at the exact error.  Sorry guys.

Answer (score 4):

The line `num = random.randint(0,9)` sets `num` to an `int`, and so when `fillaray` returns `num` (assuming `size > 0`), it is returning an `int`, not a list, and this `int` is then passed to `totalOdds` and `totalEvens`, which try to subscript it (i.e., do `num[i]`) as though it were a list, which is an error.  Presumably, what you want to do is to append the random `int`s to the list `num` instead of overwriting it, e.g., by doing `num.append(random.randint(0,9))`.